# Evaluate $\iint_{[0,1]^2} (1+x^2+y^2)^{-3/2} dxdy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> Evaluate $\iint_{[0,1]^2} (1+x^2+y^2)^{-3/2} dxdy$

Mobile keyboard doesn't support many features. Please apologize me with this issue and solve this.

Comment: A good idea is to learn MathJAX so that you can write pretty formulae. Although it's a PITA to write on mobile "keyboard" it should be possible. I've (well Robert Z too) updated the formulae, please take time to check that they're correct. Also update the body of the question...

Comment: @RajatDash What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the integral is symmetric under the interchange of variables $x \leftrightarrow y$, so we can cut our region of integration in half with the line $y=x$. The integral on the top half will equal the integral on the bottom half, so we can double the value of one of them.

Writing the integral of the bottom half of the square, it is best to do the integral in polar coordinates:

$$\iint_{[0,1]^2} (1+x^2+y^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}} dA = 2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \int_0^{\sec\theta} \frac{r}{(1+r^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}drd\theta$$

$$ = 2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sec^2\theta}}d\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} - \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{2}{\sqrt{1+\sec^2\theta}}d\theta$$

Focusing on the integral left over, use the substitution

$$1+\sec^2\theta = 2\cosh^2t \implies d\theta = \frac{\sqrt{2}\cosh t}{\cosh 2t}dt$$

The integral then simplifies to

$$\int_0^{\cosh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)} \frac{2\sqrt{2}\cosh t}{\sqrt{2\cosh^2t}\cosh 2t}dt = \int_0^{\cosh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)} \frac{2}{\cosh 2t} dt$$

Then multiply top and bottom by $\cosh 2t$ and use the hyperbolic identity $\cosh^2 2t = 1 + \sinh^2 2t$:

$$ = \int_0^{\cosh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)} \frac{2\cosh 2t}{1+ \sinh^2 2t}dt = \tan^{-1}\left(\sinh 2t\right)\Biggr|_0^{\cosh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)}$$

$$=\tan^{-1}\left(2\sinh t \cosh t\right)\Bigr|_{t=\cosh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)} = \tan^{-1}\left(2\cosh t\sqrt{\cosh^2t-1} \right)\Bigr|_{t=\cosh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)}$$

$$ = \tan^{-1}(\sqrt{3}) = \frac{\pi}{3}$$

So our final answer is $\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{3} = \frac{\pi}{6}$.

Comment: Thanks Ninad, for helping me in this problem.

Answer (score 3):

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx dy}{(1+x^2+yt^2)^{3/2}}$$ Let us use the integral representation of $z^{-3/2}$ as $$\int_{0}^{\infty}t^2 e^{-z t^2} dt = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4 z^{3/2}}.$$
Then $$I= \frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} t^2 e^{-(1+x^2+y^2)t^2} dt dx dy$$  $$I== \int_{0}^{\infty} t^2  e^{-t^2} dt\int_{0}^{1} e^{-x^2t^2} dx \int_{0}^{1} e^{-y^2 t^2} dy  =\sqrt{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t^2} {Erf}^2(t) dt. $$ Take $Erf(t)=u \implies \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-t^2} dt =du$
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2} \int_{0}^{1} u^2 du= \frac{\pi}{6}. $$

Comment: Thanks Zafar for your solution. Thanks

Comment: How to upvote ? It's saying that "you can't upvote this comment"

Comment: +1 Pretty fine.

Comment: @Felix Mann Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The brutal way (integrating with respect to $x$, then with respect to $y$) also works pretty fast:

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{(1+x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\,dx\,dy = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dy}{(1+y^2)\sqrt{2+y^2}}. $$
By substituting $y=\tan\theta$ we get
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{2+\tan^2\theta}}=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{2-\sin^2\theta}}\,d\theta\stackrel{\sin(\theta)\mapsto u}{=}\int_{0}^{1/\sqrt{2}}\frac{du}{\sqrt{2-u^2}}\stackrel{u\mapsto v\sqrt{2}}{=}\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{dv}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}$$
and the RHS equals $\arcsin\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\pi}{6}$.

Comment: Actually I can't integrate w.r.t x

Comment: @RajatDash: consider that $\int\frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}=C+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ allows to evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(x^2+A^2)^{3/2}}$ through the substitution $x=At$.